# Globular cluster star density as a function of distance from the center

Tags: globular-clusters

Context: I want to simulate globular clusters in a simple way, just to display the positions of stars.

Assuming isotropy, what would be a reasonable model of the stellar number density as a function or r, the distance from the center of the cluster?

I'm assuming that such a model would have some free parameters as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual thing is a [King model](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1966AJ.....71...64K).

There are indeed free parameters. These are the central density, the "core radius" and a tidal truncation radius.

The background and rationale for these models is given in the link. They provide a pretty good representation of the surface density of globular clusters (or indeed open clusters). They require a numerical scheme to "deproject" from the plane of the sky to 3D.

If you find the nitty-gritty of Abel integrals too tricky in the deprojection, then you could always approximate with a [Plummer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plummer_model). This is analytically and computationally easier to deal with, but lacks a bit of physical realism. Central density and a characteristic radius are free parameters here.

Comment: My needs are pretty simple. I will use the Plummer model.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [MASSCLEAN](http://bogdan.massclean.org/massclean.html) package, it can be used to generate artificial/synthetic clusters of arbitrary metallicities, ages, mass, radius (based on a King profile distribution) and even includes field stars contamination.

Here's an example of a cluster generated with the code (right) imitating a known cluster (NGC 3603, left):

[image]

See the [original article](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:0811.4210) for a good description of the capabilities of the code.

Comment: That does look handy. How is the field star contamination handled?

Comment: It can generate an artificial one (based on the model presented in http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992ApJS...83..111W & http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994AJ....107..582C) or it can include a real stellar field.  More details in Sect 2.5 of the original article.